# mobx computed property observing computed property does not recalcuoate

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have the following 2 computed properties, the first is based off an observable `password`:

```
@observable password = '';

@computed
get passwordRules() {
    return [
        {isValid: !!((this.password.length >= 8) && (this.password.indexOf(' ') < 0 )), label: pageConstants.TIP_1},
        {isValid: !!this.password.match('^(?=.*[A-Z])'), label: pageConstants.TIP_2},
        {isValid: !!this.password.match('^(?=.*[a-z])'), label: pageConstants.TIP_3},
        {isValid: !!this.password.match('^(?=.*[0-9])'), label: pageConstants.TIP_4},
        {isValid: !!this.password.match('^(?=.*[-~!@#€=?_<>£"{}\[\\]\+\(\)\$%\^&\*])'), label: pageConstants.TIP_5}
    ];
}

@computed
get passwordIsValid() {
    return !some(this.passwordRules, rule => !rule.isValid);
}
```

I would like the `passwordIsValid` to recalculate whenever any item in the passwordRules array changes but this is not currently happening.

`passwordIsValid` is only accessed the first time it is called and does not recalculate whenever any of the isValid property changes in the `passwordRules` array.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `passwordRules` does not return something observable, so there is nothing for MobX to track. Probably you need `@observable passwordRules = [{ isValid ... }]` if you intend to modify them in the future. It seems like you handle passwordRules as *state*, rather then a derived value (which should not be modified directly as it is *derived*)

Comment: so passwordRules. changes whenever an observable string password changes.  if i make passwordRules observable then it won't recalculate.

Comment: Is it not possible to base a computed property off another computed property?

Comment: yes that is no problem, the problem is that there are no observable data structures in here. So `passwordRules()` will never update because there is no data it used that updates. If you do something like `passwordRules[0].isValid` you are modifying the *output* of the computed function instead of it's input. Currently there are no observables at all in your example.....

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Yes but a computed property should not mutate anything or at least not in a get.  Is there a way of specifying that when one thing changes a property updates without any sort of mutation or some sort of cascade?

Comment: actually changing password isValid to return an array means the cp fires every time password changes:  this.passwordRules.filter(rule => !rule.isValid);

Comment: I think your missing my point. Would you care to setup a fiddle? You could fork e.g. jsfiddle.net/mweststrate/wv3yopo0/

Comment: great, i'll create a fiddle, in new to mobx

Comment: here is a jsfiddle although it works in this example.  If I am being honest, I did not understand your point.  Could you explain it http://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/m9tu8ehm/